# Business Catalyst Server to Server automated request solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, business-catalyst

Before I dive into another quest in Business Catalyst... I was wondering if anybody has managed to do any server to server automated **PUT-GET-POST** requests on an automated base system, basically, I wanted to create a stock management connected to another service that updates the stock without going to BC and sync stocks every day.

Bc supports OAuth as a server to server connection not sure if it has been tested before with another service using an automated app, I could not find anybody in the forums that did it but what I need is quite today's requirements for any service connecting to another server nobody wants to go every day and update stuff manually.

Thanks and I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I've built it in Django. You have to get everything right to get it working. Make sure you read the docs very carefully. The messages those endpoints return are terrible or non-existent.

I followed this document https://docs.worldsecuresystems.com/developers/apps/server-to-server-service

They have an app written in Node and if I was to build this again I'd use Node.

Good luck!